# Delphi XE5 TIdUDPServer does not receive anything on Android

Tags: android, delphi, indy, delphi-xe5

I have a TIdUDPServer on a form setup with a default port and broadcast mode enabled and cannot get it to receive anything under Android.

The same code is working fine under iOS but if I retarget Android I do not receive anything.

Is there a trick I am missing. I have checked the "User Permissions" and turn on everything I think might influence this but have had no luck with getting it working.

Thanks in advance, Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you Remy for putting me on the right track.
Here is the complete code to receive broadcast UDP packets...

```
unit Androidapi.JNI.WiFiManager;

interface

uses
  Androidapi.JNIBridge, Androidapi.Jni,  androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes, androidapi.JNI.Net,
  androidapi.JNI.Os, FMX.Helpers.Android, Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText, SysUtils;

Type
  JWiFiManager = interface;   // android/net/wifi/WifiManager
  JMulticastLock = interface; // android/net/wifi/WifiManager$MulticastLock

  JWiFiManagerClass = interface(JObjectClass)
   ['{F69F53AE-BC63-436A-8F69-57389B30CAA8}']
    function getSystemService(Contex: JString): JWiFiManager; cdecl;
  end;

  [JavaSignature('android/net/wifi/WifiManager')]
  JWiFiManager = interface(JObject)
  ['{382E85F2-6BF8-4255-BA3C-03C696AA6450}']
    function createMulticastLock(tag: JString): JMulticastLock;
  end;

  TJWiFiManager = class(TJavaGenericImport<JWiFiManagerClass, JWiFiManager>) end;

  JMulticastLockClass = interface(JObjectClass)
  ['{C0546633-3DF2-46B0-8E2C-C14411674A6F}']
  end;

  [JavaSignature('android/net/wifi/WifiManager$MulticastLock')]
  JMulticastLock = interface(JObject)
  ['{CFA00D0C-097C-45E3-8B33-0E5A6C9FB9F1}']
    procedure acquire();
    function isHeld(): Boolean;
    procedure release();
    procedure setReferenceCounted(refCounted: boolean);
  end;

  TJMulticastLock = class(TJavaGenericImport<JMulticastLockClass, JMulticastLock>) end;

  function GetWiFiManager: JWiFiManager;

implementation

function GetWiFiManager: JWiFiManager;
var
  Obj: JObject;
begin
  Obj := SharedActivityContext.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.WIFI_SERVICE);
  if not Assigned(Obj) then
    raise Exception.Create('Could not locate Wifi Service');
  Result := TJWiFiManager.Wrap((Obj as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
  if not Assigned(Result) then
    raise Exception.Create('Could not access Wifi Manager');
end;
```

And then to acquire the necessary lock...

```
wifi_manager := GetWiFiManager;
multiCastLock := wifi_manager.createMulticastLock(StringToJString('LightFactory Remote'));
multiCastLock.setReferenceCounted(true);
multiCastLock.acquire;
```

Finally dont forget the permissions mentioned in Remy's post.

Comment: As an FYI to future readers: these interfaces are now defined in `androidapi.JNI.Net`. Don't forget to release the lock when you don't need it anymore to save battery life.

Answer (score 5):

Is your device connected to WiFi or a mobile network? UDP does not work over mobile unless you initiate an outgoing UDP connection first to open up the mobile's carrier's firewall.

Are the UDP packets being sent directly to the device's IP or to a broadcast IP?  By default, Android discards UDP packets that are not addressed directly to the device's IP. For multicast packets, [`WifiManager.createMulticastLock()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#createMulticastLock(java.lang.String)) must been called beforehand to allow such packets, and you need to include the [`CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE) permission in the app's manifest.  That might apply to UDP broadcasts as well, I am not sure.

Comment: To add to this, broadcasting (as opposed to direct address) IS accepted by Android provided that the UDP component `active` property is `true` (one of the first tests I did with Android-XE5 was UDP broadcast between PC and tablet in same wifi network and it functioned with very few issues). I'd still advise to send out a broadcast from the device first to let others on the network know that the device is there (and so that it 'opens up' the connection to the LAN), and then use the `ABinding.PeerIP` const from the `TIDUdpServer.OnUDPRead` event as a direct IP to `.send()` to.

Comment: Thank you that sounds like the problem I am have. I am very new to this and cannot find anything online about how to access the WiFiManger from within Delphi.
androidapi.??? maybe?

Comment: @ScottPritchard Thanks but the discovery is one way for my application and not something I can change. The PC broadcasts messages onto the network to say its available and I need to catch them.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any experience using Delphi for Android yet, so I can't provide exact code for accessing Android classes, but in theory any Android Java class should be accessible with a little work. There are a few third party units already floating around to access various Android APIs in Delphi, so search for them and see how they do it, especially on the Embarcadero forums.

Comment: This I believe is how it should look...
    `wifi_manager: JWiFiManager;`
    `wifi_manager := SharedActivityContext.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.WIFI_SERVICE);`
However I am not able to find an interface definition for what I am guessing should be called JWiFiManager. 
I would have thought it would be in Androidapi.JNI.Net but I cant find it anywhere.

Comment: Yes, that is the jist of it. But like any other platform API that Delphi supports, its default Android units do not implement EVERYTHING exposed by Android.  Chances are that you will have to manually declare the missing interfaces in your own code. Look at the source code for Delphi's existing Android support units in the $(BDS)\Source\RTL\Android folder to see how to access Android APIs via JNI.